# Depth of hole when burying a 2 inch schedule 40 pole

Tags: concrete, pole

How deep of a hole do I need, and how much concrete is needed for 21 foot tall 2 inch steel pipe schedule 40 pole that will be free standing?  There will be a 19 foot tall antenna on top of it.vertical with lots of stuff spreading out in multiple directions? I do not wont guy wires. the antenna be sticking up another 19 feet from the top of the pipe. The soil is clay.

Comment: So you're planning to use a 21' tall 2" Schedule 40 pipe to hold an antenna of some sort?  I don't think a 21' tall pipe like that will even support itself much less an antenna with a wind load at the top.

Comment: You now have a mix of "steel pipe" and "schedule 40 pole". Please revise thoroughly (including the title) so the question is answerable.

Comment: Also: Is the antenna a single horizontal piece going across, centered on the top of the pole? Or more vertical? Or something with lots of stuff spreading out in multiple directions?

Comment: How many guy wires do you plan for support?  A 2” pole at 20’ is going to flop around now matter how good of a base it has. I had a triangle 18” tower that was 18” only 50’ tall and had to have 6 guy wires 3 close to the top then 3 more down 20’. That only had a few dipole elements and no reflectors.

Comment: Presumably 2" schedule 40 steel pipe. i.e. 2.38" OD 0.15" wall. But it depends what you are setting it in (bedrock, sand, clay...) and how much movement is acceptable, plus wind loading (...will the antenna be sticking up another 19 feet from the top of the pipe?) Seems unlikely to be stable enough for most purposes as a monopole (no guy wires), but a flagpole site might be informative...or illustrative of what might be needed.)